# php - casting a decimal to negative

Tags: php, floating-point, integer

this is probably ridiculously simple but I'm not sure how to do this properly and couldn't find anything - if I have a positive decimal number, e.g 0.04, what's the best way to cast this to a negative value in PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$var = 0.04;

$neg = -$var; // easiest
$neg = -1 * $var; // bit more explicit
$neg = 0 - $var; // another version
```

Comment: Oh, and if you're firing arbitrary numbers at this, where some may be negative, you can explicitly check for negativity before hand, or pass it through `abs()` to force it to positive, THEN negate.

Comment: Cheers - I was already using your first suggestion but it didn't work because I wasn't using the correct data. Which always helps! Thanks for the breakdown of the other options for doing this